# Can such material exist?

Tags: materials

Can a solid material exist, such that it shatters if you hit it lightly (with a solid object) but it deforms and doesn't shatter if you hit it hard (say with a hammer)?

Comment: I'd say this is more a physics question than chemistry.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question; however, you might want to have a look at [Bologna bottles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_bottle).

Comment: @paracetamol I think it's quite straightforward and everyone understands what I'm mean. If you wish, we could define "hard and light" as pressure. It doesn't matter at what pressure the result changes, the point is that there exists such point which determines whether the object gets shattered or deformed. Where shattering occurs at lower pressure than deformation.

Comment: @paracetamol Imagine a material which shatters like glass when you drop it on the floor but it gets deformed like wax when you smash it with a force of a hammer.

Comment: Ah well, I suppose I was nitpicking more than I should have. I see your point, and I stand corrected. I voted to reopen.